# Subsetting data for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have data saved in multiple datasets, each consisting of four variables. Imagine something like a data.table `dt` consisting of the variables `Country`, `Male/Female`, `Birthyear`, `Weighted Average Income`. I would like to create a graph where you see only one country's weighted average income by birthyear and split by male/female. I've used the `facet_grid()` function to get a grid of graphs for all countries as below.

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_line(data = dt,
           aes(x = Birthyear, 
               y = Weighted Average Income,
               colour = 'Weighted Average Income'))+
 facet_grid(Country ~ Male/Female)
```

However, I've tried isolating the graphs for just one country, but the below code doesn't seem to work. How can I subset the data correctly?

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_line(data = dt[Country == 'Germany'],
           aes(x = Birthyear, 
               y = Weighted Average Income,
               colour = 'Weighted Average Income'))+
 facet_grid(Country ~ Male/Female)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case the problem is that you are not quoting `Male/Female` and `Weighted Average Income`. Also your data and basic aesthetics should likely be part of `ggplot` and not `geom_line`. Doing so isolates these to the single layer, and you would have to add the code to every layer of your plot if you were to add for example `geom_smooth`.

So to fix your problem you could do

```
library(tidyverse)
plot <- ggplot(data = dt[Country == 'Germany'], 
       aes(x = Birthyear, 
           y = sym("Weighted Average Income"),
           col = sym("Weighted Average Income")
       ) + #Could use "`x`" instead of sym(x) 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(Country ~ sym("Male/Female")) ##Could use "`x`" instead of sym(x)
plot
```

Now `ggplot2` actually has a (lesser known) builtin functionality for changing your data, so if you wanted to compare this to the plot with all of your countries included you could do:

```
plot %+% dt # `%+%` is used to change the data used by one or more layers. See help("+.gg")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The missing quotes were actually an error of mine in composing the question. I actually found another way in the meantime. I simply used the subset function on dt, so I did ggplot(data = subset(dt, Country == 'Germany'). For some reason, the bracket notation did not work for me and continued giving me errors, that the lengths didn't match. Any idea what might have caused this?

Comment: So the specific bracket notation you were using is a subsetting method special to the `data.table` package. If you are receiving errors, I believe you might have seen it somewhere but not known that it is only used for `data.table`s and not `data.frame`s? It is similar to `with(dt, dt[Country == 'Germany', ])` (although much MUCH more efficient and fast!) In base R we would more commonly do `dt[dt$Country == "Germany", ]`. Note that the comma is necessary in base R while it is not in `data.table`!