# subsetting a ggplot2 by color after its creation

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I have a collection of ggplots that I want to explore.
The creation of these ggplots is complicated, and it would be hard for me to change the way they are made.

My goal is to subset a plot to show only one color group, like it is done using `plotly::ggplotly()` (HTML plots).

I expect it should be similar to the way we subset a plot to the `x` dimension using `xlim()`, but for the `color` dimension.
However, it seems that it does not seem to work the same way.

Here is a reproducible example with expected output:

```r
library(tidyverse)
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
#initial plot
p
```

[image]

```r
#subset on x
p + lims(x=c(15,20)) #same as xlim(15, 20)
#> Warning: Removed 19 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
#subset on color (fail)
p + lims(color="6")
```

[image]

```r
#expected output (without data manipulation)
ggplot(mtcars %>% filter(cyl==6), 
       aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As you can see, instead of subsetting on color, it only removed the color attribute.

Note that, with the `x` dimension there was a warning about removing values, whereas there was not with the `color` dimension.

Is there a way to subset the plot after its creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `ggplot` object has a member called `data`, which is a data frame you can filter, so you could create a little function that filters based on existing variables:

```r
filter_ggplot <- function(p, predicate) {
  predicate <- match.call()$predicate
  backup    <- p$data
  p$data    <- p$data[with(backup, eval(predicate)),]
  print(p)
  p$data    <- backup
  invisible(p)
}
```

This allows:

```r
p
```

[image]

```r
p %>% filter_ggplot(cyl == 6)
```

[image]

```r
p %>% filter_ggplot(cyl == 4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Great! I could even one-line it without additional function, although your syntax is probably clearer and more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Allan's answer and some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66583582/3888000), I could make a one-liner out of my problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)
p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, color=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
p %+% filter(p$data, cyl==6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>